# Is regex uuid validator is safe for untrusted strings

Tags: javascript, uuid, denial-of-service

I'm using a [uuid package](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) which can validate if string is a UUID.
I'm afraid of [ReDOS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS). Is this regex exposed to ReDOS attacks? maybe other attacks I don't think about?

```
/^(?:[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)$/i
```

Currently I slice the string before pass it to the function, but it's cumbersome and less readable:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
flow(s => s.slice(0, 36), console.log)('uuid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OWASP article you linked has your answer. A pattern is considered "Evil" (vulnerable to a ReDOS attack) if it contains repetition inside a repeated group.

> ## Evil Regexes
>
> A Regex is called “evil” if it can stuck on crafted input.
>
> Evil Regex pattern contains:
>
> - Grouping with repetition
> - Inside the repeated group:
>
>   - Repetition
>   - Alternation with overlapping

---

Your pattern does not have grouping inside of repetition so it is not vulnerable. That said, if you know you expect a UUID inside the first 36 characters of the string you are searching, there is an efficiency benefit to trimming the string  before you attempt to match. I don't know if the splice is hard enough to read to warrant the extra time searching your string, you'll have to judge that for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There's zero chance of ReDOS with this pattern — it doesn't contain any variable repeats, or any alternation inside of repeats. It's a very simple pattern that validates each character and moves on to the next.